# changing code in Java class file with dependencies

Tags: java, compilation

I started off with a .jar file that I unzipped. I need to change a few lines of code in just ONE of the classes contained in the contents of that jar file. I went about this as follows:

1) opened the class in Java Decompiler to view the source.

2) copied source to a new text file and saved with ".java" extension.

3) in command line I went to jdk folder and executed  javac Classname.java to recompile.

However this class code imports some dependencies so the recompile failed. I have the dependencies, they were part of the original jar file contents but they are all compiled .class files and spread across several folders...

Is it possible to re-compile this class successfully? Is there command line code to include dependencies?

Comment: Wouldn't you just specify the extra dependencies in the class path (`-cp` or `-classpath`) when you compile using [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)? How are you executing the `javac` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the `-classpath` option.

```
javac -classpath original.jar Modified.java
```

Then, you can remove the old class from the jar file and insert the new one.  There isn't a simple way to do this via command line, so I recommend an archive application such as [WinRAR](http://www.win-rar.com/start.html?&L=0) or [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).

Comment: excellent thanks. it looked a tad simpler than first so I went with it, thanks both!